# Receiving an Asynchronous Response on Zabbix Server

Tags: zabbix

I have a series of IoT devices that I would like to monitor with Zabbix that can not run the Zabbix agent. To monitor the devices I would like to have a server send a web request to these devices and get the response, however these devices work by sending both a synchronous response to the requesting server as well as an asynchronous response to a provided URL which contains the actual data that was requested. What we want to do is monitor the contents of the asynchronous response with Zabbix. Is there a way to set up Zabbix to receive both the synchronous and asynchronous responses? The alternative would be a rather lengthy process involving writing a daemon and reports data to the Zabbix agent on the Zabbix server, which is undesirable to say the least.

Comment: What exactly do you want to monitor? Do you want to asynchronously send data to the Zabbix server, or monitor some asynchronous process on the system itself?

Comment: I'd like to have a URI on the Zabbix server that I can have the request send the asynchronous response to, and have Zabbix basically say "this endpoint returned this response". it would know what "this endpoint" is by reading the XML returned in the asynchronous payload.

Comment: But what's your functional goal? Just dump them in Zabbix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the goal is not fully clear yet, most likely you can use the [zabbix_sender](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manpages/zabbix_sender) utility or implement the [Zabbix sender protocol](https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/protocols/zabbix_sender/3.4).